# How to know when all my Producer - Consumer jobs have finished

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have `Winforms` application that read several network folders and search for files inside this folders, this function receive `List<stirng> folders`:

```
private decimal _numberOfFiles;
private static List<string> _folders;
public delegate void OnFileAddDelegate(List<string> files);
public event OnFileAddDelegate OnFileAddEventHandler;
public delegate void OnFinishSearchDelegate();
public event OnFinishSearchDelegate OnFinishSearchEventHandler;

public void SearchFiles()
{
    foreach (string folder in _folders)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(folder))
        {
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.doc", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .OrderByDescending(x => new FileInfo(x).CreationTime).Take((int)_numberOfFiles).ToList<string>();
            if (OnFileAddEventHandler != null)
                OnFileAddEventHandler(files);
        }
    }

    if (OnFinishSearchEventHandler != null)
        OnFinishSearchEventHandler();
}
```

After `OnFileAddEventHandler(files)` event is fired my `ProducerConsumer` class start to check this `List` of files that found and do the work (if the file is OK fired up event to my main UI to add this files into my `ListView`):

```
public class ProducerConsumer
{
    public delegate void OnFileAddDelegate(PcapFileDetails pcapFileDetails);
    public event OnFileAddDelegate OnFileAddEventHandler;
    public delegate void AllFilesProcessedDelegate();
    public event AllFilesProcessedDelegate AllFilesProcessedEventHandler;
    private readonly Queue<string> _queue;
    private int counter;

    public ProducerConsumer(int workerCount, IEnumerable<string> list)
    {
        _isSearchFinished = true;
        _queue = new Queue<string>(list); // fill the queue
        counter = _queue.Count; // set up counter
        for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Consumer);
    }

    private void Consumer()
    {
        FileChecker fileChecker = new FileChecker();
        for (; ; )
        {
            string file;
            lock (_queue)
            {
                // synchronize on the queue
                if (_queue.Count == 0) return;  // we are done
                file = _queue.Dequeue(); // get file name to process
            } // release the lock to allow other consumers to access the queue
            // do the job
            string result = fileChecker.Check(file); // Check my file

            if (OnFileAddEventHandler != null && result ) // In case my file OK, fired up event to my main UI
                OnFileAddEventHandler(file);

            // decrement the counter
            if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter) != 0)
                continue; // not the last

            // all done - we were the last
            if (AllFilesProcessedEventHandler != null)
                AllFilesProcessedEventHandler();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Now while this search is in process  my UI is locked to prevent unnecessary clicks and i want to know when all my folders finish to search to unlock.
But my problem is because i am search several folders the event `AllFilesProcessedEventHandler()` fired up several times and i want to know when all my searches finished.

Comment: Which version of .NET do you use? 4.5 or earlier?

Comment: Is there a reason that you use a queue?Why not pass a folder as an argument to the function so you can avoid the lock?Can you do that?

Comment: I don't want to stop using my lock cause if i will press start in the middle my application is still adding files the results can be that my application will behave erratically

Comment: Take a look at me answer.Do you see something you cannot do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive sample with QuickIO.Net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SchwabenCode.QuickIO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly BlockingCollection<QuickIOFileInfo> fileInfos = new BlockingCollection<QuickIOFileInfo>();
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Int32 totalSize = 0;
                Parallel.ForEach(fileInfos.GetConsumingEnumerable(), fi =>
                {
                    Interlocked.Add(ref totalSize, (int)fi.Bytes);
                });
                Console.WriteLine("All docs bytes amount to {0}", totalSize);
            });

            ProcessDirectory("C:\\");
            fileInfos.CompleteAdding();

            Task.WaitAll(task);
        }

        private static void ProcessDirectory(string path)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(QuickIODirectory.EnumerateDirectories(path), dir =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(QuickIODirectory.EnumerateFiles(dir), file =>
                    {
                        if (file.AsFileInfo().Extension.Equals(".docx"))
                            fileInfos.Add(file);
                    });
                    ProcessDirectory(dir.FullName);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to access directory {0}", dir.FullName);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Blocking collection will automatically signal to Parallel ForEach when all elements have been added, by calling CompleteAdding().

To scan a 256GB SSD, with 74GB left and total of 738k+ files took 16.8s.

Comment: Why use `Interlocked.Add`? A simple Map-Reduce seems more efficient, and non-blocking. The only reason for an `Interlocked.Add` is if you want to check the running tally. Even then it is possible to batch your Map-Reduce (slightly harder, but do able).

Comment: True, but the sample by no means is production quality code. It was just to demonstrate how to proceed with his challenge without reinventing the blocking collection from scratch.

Comment: `.AsParallel().Sum(fi => (int)fi.Bytes)`

Comment: @Aron thanks for your comments. I suspect user3637066 will want to do more than just sum the size of files.

Comment: What's is QuickIOFileInfo ?

Comment: A superfast IO library. http://quickio.net/ Just add it to your project `Install-package QuickIO.Net`. 44,000 files per second on my SSD.

Comment: @Aron BTW, using Map-Reduce might have shortened the time by 20%. But than again, user is not just summarizing sizes. Nice suggestion nevertheless.

Comment: I don't need the recursion so i moved the first Parallel.ForEach and it crashed

Comment: Since I don't know how you "moved", I can't really tell why it crashed. Sounds to me you need to play with C# a little and gain more experience. Keep up the good work!